# TailwindCSS Typography responsive variants not including extended class selector

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS and its Typography plugin. In particular, I am using the `prose` class and trying to extend it.

The full code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mayer-zxw2b?file=/tailwind.config.js&resolutionWidth=700&resolutionHeight=675

The container has `prose sm:prose-lg` so that `prose-lg` is applied after the `sm` breakpoint. I extend the `prose` classes so that a default color is applied and a second color is applied to children with a particular class (the selector is `"> .lighter-color"`).

Below the `sm` breakpoint, the colors are `#00a` and `#00f`, as expected.
After the `sm` breakpoint, the colors should be changed to `#0a0` and `#0f0`, respectively. The first color does change to `#0a0` but the second color doesn't change.

For some reason, the `"> .lighter-color"` selector is included in `prose` but not in `sm:prose-lg`. I think it works for `prose-lg` so I suspect it might be a problem about the responsive variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is an issue with TailwindCSS, as described [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3361#issuecomment-773350252).